# How to declare a type that get a Type in tuntime like Tuple

Tags: c#, generics

Please consider `Tuple` declaration:

```
public static class Tuple
{
    public static Tuple<T1> Create<T1>(T1 item1);
    public static Tuple<T1, T2> Create<T1, T2>(T1 item1, T2 item2);
    public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3> Create<T1, T2, T3>(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3);
    ....
```

we can declare a `Tuple` variable like this:

```
Tuple<Mycls> a = new Tuple<Mycls>(new Mycls());
```

Now I want to declare my type like `Tuple` that can get a type(class) in runtime.I wrote this:

```
public static class Nime
{
    public static Nime<T1> Create<T1>(T1 item1);
}
```

but I got this error:

> The non-generic type 'Nime' cannot be used with type arguments

How I can declare a class like `Tuple` that get type in run time.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what you you are trying to emulate

You want the following:

```
class Nime<T> { ... }

static class Nime
{
  public static Nime<T> Create<T>(T t) { return new Nime<T> { ... } }
}
```

Note: `Nime` and `Nime<T>` are distinct types. The former being the 'factory' class.

Usage:

```
var n = Nime.Create("foo"); // var is Nime<string>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
public class Nime<T1>
{
    public static Nime<T1> Create(T1 item1)
    {
        return new Nime<T1>(item1); 
    }

    public T1 Item { get; set; }

    private Nime(T1 item)
    {
        Item = item;
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
var n = Nime<string>.Create("foo");
Console.WriteLine(n.Item);
```

And the output of course is "foo".